# How to change path gains in rayleighchan MatLab?

Tags: matlab, communication, telecommunication

I am trying to simulate a channel with multipath and fading in MatLab using the function *rayleighchan* and I want to change the path gains, because the function put them randomly. I have spent a lot of hours trying to do it and reading documentation, but I haven't been able to do it. Could Someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried as it is difficult to offer help on such a generalised question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because what you are really looking for is changing the `AvgPathGainsdB`, and not `PathGains`.

### Explanation

Understand that multi-path fading is a complex process, more so when Doppler spread is involved. The Rayleigh channel class (`rayleighchan`) generates non-LOS multi-path channels that are characterized by Rayleigh fading.

The variables `PathDelays` are the excess delays due to each multi-path component, where each path has an amplitude that is Rayleigh distributed, and phase that is uniformly distributed.

The *mean amplitude* for the Rayleigh distribution of each path is decided by the average path gains property (`AvgPathGainsdB`), while the exact amplitudes are statistically generated in `PathGains`.

### Example

If you want a three path channel, where the delays of the paths are [0, 10, 50] us, with *average* path gains of [0, -3, -5] dB, do the following:

```
rchan = rayleighchan([0, 10e-6, 50e-6], [0, -3, -5]);
```

If there is Doppler spread, the `PathGains` change over time, as you filter your signal through this object.

Comment: On a side note, I believe you should spend some time understanding how channel models are simulated and generated statistically, as that is a different concept to the theory.